# Turtlebot, is it open source hardware?

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is the Turtlebot open source hardware ? Or, can I get into serious legal mess if I tinker with the design ? What sort of license is there for the Turtlebot ?

**UPDATE**
@Ryan I am using this logo for my robot ! :-)

[image description http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-eX34zCK43mU/UU7noVcZLFI/AAAAAAAACaE/sAGXU8TLd6Y/s1600/tortue-2.jpg](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-eX34zCK43mU/UU7noVcZLFI/AAAAAAAACaE/sAGXU8TLd6Y/s1600/tortue-2.jpg)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12470/turtlebot,-is-it-open-source-hardware-?/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2011-12-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-04-22**:
I would love to see some Hindi in your logo! :-)

**Comment by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on 2013-04-23**:
Yeah me too :) Some sanskrit as well, kachuabot ;)

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-04-23**:
LOL !!! ... well ! ... it is too late to make amends now .... ;-) Jokes apart, I was looking for an amicable translation of the word turtle (for obvious reasons) I went to 'Tortuga' which is Spanish, but the French had a nice sing to it ! To-r-tu-e ! .... 'Kachuabot' would seem rather Desi ! ;-)

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-04-23**:
+1 to kachuabot! :-P

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-04-23**:
@bit-pirate spare me ! ...... LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Quoting from [turtlebot.com](http://turtlebot.com)

> TurtleBot is an open source hardware project as described by the [Open Source Hardware Statement of Principles and Definition v1.0](http://freedomdefined.org/OSHW).
> It is released under the [FreeBSD Documentation License](http://www.freebsd.org/copyright/freebsd-doc-license.html).

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2011-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As well, it may be worth mentioning that though the design is fully open-source, the "TurtleBot" logo and trademark is a Willow Garage property. Each of the manufacturing partners have committed to quality standards in order to continue branding the TurtleBots we produce as "TurtleBots".

Of course, this doesn't stop anyone from producing their own full robots or drastically modifying the design. Have fun!

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2011-12-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-12-27**:
@Ryan : Hmmmm ..... so, I will have to make my own logo and stickers ..... ;-)